# Probability that the minimum of a Normal sample is greater than the maximum of another sample, with different variances.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, order-statistics

Suppose I sample $k$ i.i.d. elements $x_{1i},...,x_{1k}$ from a normal $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_1)$ distribution, and I sample a separate $k$ i.i.d. elements $x_{2i},...,x_{2k}$ from a normal $\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_2)$ distribution, with $\sigma_1 \ne \sigma_2$.

> What is the probability that $\min_i(x_{1i}) > \max_i(x_{2i})$?

That is, what is the probability that all of the elements in the first sample are greater than all of those in the second sample?

I know when $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2$ this [reduces to a combinatorics problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163531).

But what about when the variances of the two groups are unequal? I've tried formulating this using the extreme-value distribution, but have had minimum luck. For example, if we let $m_1=\min(x_{1i})$ and $M_2=max(x_{2i})$ we can write:

$$P(m_1>M_2) = \int_a P(m_1>a \mid M_2=a)\, f_{M_2}(a)$$

And then $f_{M_2}(a)$ can be approximated by pdf of the extreme value distribution, and $P(m_1>a \mid M_2=a)$ can be approximated by the cdf of the extreme value distribution. But this gets really messy and I can't find a closed-form solution.  I'm hoping there's a simpler and more intuitive approach to take.

Any suggestions or thoughts? Thanks!